# Ubuntu 13.10 Empathy cannot login two Google accounts at the same time

Tags: 13.10, empathy

I have two Google accounts. Ubuntu 13.10 configured to handle both accounts with Empathy. When Empathy starts, only one account is enabled. In Empathy main dialog (where the contacts are shown), there is an icon, showing that the not connected Google account must be configured to be used.

When that icon is clicked, the system **Online Accounts** dialog is shown, with both accounts connected and properly configured. After that, Empathy just doesn't show the contacts of the failed Google account, neither the chat windows.

Anyone of both accounts can be in this state, seems to be random at Empathy start. If the not connected account is reset in the Online Accounts dialog, it is automatically connected, but the before connected account is disconnected, and the same Online Accounts icon is shown in the Empathy main dialog (the same problem, but with the previously connected account).

- Somebody knows whats happening?